# Como funcionam os watchers do AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, watch

No AngularJS, existe o *two-way data binding*, que faz com que os valores sejam exibidos imediatamente nas *views* mesmo quando este valor é atualizado no *controller*.

Além disso existe também a função [`$scope.$watch`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) que sabe exatamente quando uma variável é alterada e imediatamente chama uma ação quando isso acontece.

Minha pergunta é:

Como é que o AngularJS faz isso?

Eu tenho essa preocupação porque, num sistema onde tive que usar vários `ng-repeat` seguidos de `ng-models`, vários *watchers* foram gerados e, com isso, é perceptível uma grande lentidão na renderização dos elementos.

Eu sei que no Vue é utilizado uma espécie de *observer* na propriedade definida no objeto. Mas eu ainda não consegui descobrir como isso funciona no AngularJS.

- O Angular usa internamente algum tipo de *loop*, `setInterval`, ou algo do JavaScript que permite assistir a mudança do valor de variáveis? Tenho essa curiosidade no sentido de entender como isso pode afetar a performance e também para tentar fazer algo parecido.
- Se eu usar muitos *watchers* (que são gerados por `ng-if`, `ng-model` e afins, além do próprio `$scope.$watch`), posso prejudicar o desempenho da minha aplicação?

Comment: Também fiquei encasquetado com isso, sempre imaginei um trigger individual, mas recentemente me deparei com https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FMutationObserver, e creio que seja por esse caminho.

Answer (score 4):

A resposta é sim. Todas as vezes que você usar um `ng-model` , `ng-click` e etc é feito um `apply`  que é acesso ao *digest cycle*  encapsulado  junto com a execução da expression, fazendo com que toda a lista de `$watches` sejam executadas, como na imagem [image: este diagrama está na documentação do Angularjs]

Desta forma sim se você usar muitos $watchs vai prejudicar seu desempenho na página, por isso que no Angularjs deve ter cuidado com expressions que fazem chamadas de functions, pois sempre que você fizer uma simples interação na página vai ser chamada várias vezes.

Caso queiram se aprofundar mais sobre o assunto, vou deixar aqui 2 videos sobre como melhorar a performance do Angularjs.

performance 1 : https://youtu.be/6kIorm_gCO4

performance 2 : https://youtu.be/oUus56DtpO0